# Provider Hosted Application With Top and Left Nav

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app

I currently have a provider-hosted SharePoint Add-In that is using the chrome control to provider navigation back to SharePoint. What are my options to make the application feel like it is more of a part of SharePoint (Top & Left Nav) and less like a separate application?

Currently I can think of:

1. SP Hosted App + Create API for Server Logic
2. IFrame (shudders)
3. Customer Left Nav and Top Nav to mimic SP Online.

Are there any other options than those?